# Having issue when sculpting with hands/feet

Tags: sculpting

I sculpt by making individual parts and then re-meshing. It worked well, but when I get to fingers/toes, then I try to re-mesh I get this:[image]

The fingers and toes get merged together
When re-meshing, my value is already at 0.04 and I dread going lower (Blender freezes when I tried 0.01)
Any advice?

Comment: What does it give if you scale up your mesh in Edit mode then remesh?

Comment: Tried scaling it up by 3-4 times, applying all transforms and re-meshing. Barely any improvement. Here's the file. https://ufile.io/9zcsl8pb

Comment: so maybe you should spread the finger a little bit like that? https://zupimages.net/up/22/17/h0tt.jpg